# Pig: Get top n values per group

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

I have data that's already grouped and aggregated, it looks like so:

```
user    value      count
----    --------  ------
Alice   third      5
Alice   first      11
Alice   second     10
Alice   fourth     2
...
Bob     second     20
Bob     third      18
Bob     first      21
Bob     fourth     8
...
```

For every user (Alice and Bob), I want retrieve their **top n values** (let's say 2), sorted terms of 'count'.
So the desired output I want is this:

```
Alice first 11
Alice second 10
Bob first 21
Bob second 20
```

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One approach is

```
records = LOAD '/user/nubes/ncdc/micro-tab/top.txt' AS (user:chararray,value:chararray,counter:int);
grpd = GROUP records BY user;

top3 = foreach grpd {
        sorted = order records by counter desc;
        top    = limit sorted 2;
        generate group, flatten(top);
};
```

Input is:

```
Alice   third   5 
Alice   first   11 
Alice   second  10
Alice   fourth  2
Bob second  20
Bob third   18
Bob first   21
Bob fourth  8
```

Output is:

```
(Alice,Alice,first,11)
(Alice,Alice,second,10
(Bob,Bob,first,21)
(Bob,Bob,second,20)
```

Comment: limit does not guarantee that you will get the top records.

Comment: The [docs](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#LIMIT) say that doing a `limit` after you've `order`ed the collection does guarantee you get the top records

Answer (score 6):

I have just made an observation that

```
top    = limit sorted 2;
```

top is an inbuilt function and may throw an error so the only thing which I did was changed the name of the relation in this case and instead of

```
generate group, flatten(top);
```

which was giving the output

```
(Alice,Alice,first,11)
(Alice,Alice,second,10
(Bob,Bob,first,21)
(Bob,Bob,second,20)
```

Amended that as shown below -

```
records = load 'test1.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (user:chararray, value:chararray, count:int);
grpd = GROUP records BY user;
top2 = foreach grpd {
        sorted = order records by count desc;
        top1    = limit sorted 2;
        generate flatten(top1);
};
```

which gave me the desired output as required by you -

```
(Alice,first,11)
(Alice,second,10)
(Bob,first,21)
(Bob,second,20)
```

Hope this helps.